# Problems with NHibernate FlushMode Never

Tags: nhibernate, orm

We're building a large application with NHibernate as ORM layer. We've tried to apply as many best practices as possible, among which setting `FlushMode` to `Never`. However, this is giving us pain, for example the following scenario:

There is a table with an end date column. From this table, we delete the last (by end date) record:

- The record is deleted;
- After the delete, we do a (repository) query for the last record (by end date);
- This last record is updated because it's the new active record.

This is a very simple scenario, of which many exist. The problem here is that when we do the query, we get the deleted record back, which of course is not correct. This roughly means that we cannot do queries in business logic that may touch the entity being inserted or deleted, because its resp. not there yet or still there.

How can I work with this scenario? Are there ways to work around this without reverting the `FlushMode` setting or should I just give up on the `FlushMode` setting all together?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I work with this scenario? Are there ways to work around this
>   without reverting the FlushMode setting

`FlushMode.Never` does not prevent you from manually calling `Flush()` when you want to deal with up-to-date data. I guess it is the way to work this scenario without changing the `FlushMode`

> or should I just give up on the FlushMode setting all together?

Could you provide some reference on `FlushMode.Never` being a good practice in the general case ? Seems like FlushMode.Never is fit when dealing with large, mostly readonly, sets of objects.

http://jroller.com/tfenne/entry/hibernate_understand_flushmode_never

Comment: I have a number of links, but the best one probably is http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.nl/2008/12/identity-never-ending-story.html. Otherwise, https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Afabiomaulo.blogspot.com+flushmode+never gives some results from the lead developer of NHibernate.

Comment: @PietervanGinkel The post seems to aim more at preventing from using identity model which somewhat breaks UoW. I guess what is implicit (and has been made explicit in hibernate by renaming Never to Manual) is that there are cases when you need to manually flush, as NH Session is not a real database transaction scope. Or said another way, deleting your max-end-date object should be viewed as the end of an UoW. Selecting the new max-end-date object  should be viewed as the beginning of another UoW, requiring a Flush between the two UoW

Comment: No not really. There is more documentation available about CpBT, but one of the   fundamentals is that you use the flush mode. Aan example is a screen where you are editing multiple records e.g. a relation and it's addresses. You want to be able to commit or abort all mutations, and that's one of the things that CpBT gives you. I realize that I can just change the flesh mode, but I am looking for ways to mitigate the problems that the flush mode gives.

Comment: @PietervanGinkel Of course, changing the default FlushMode of an existing app would not be a good idea. Maybe the question is on the boundaries of your UoW. If your BT is about deleting/updating the top n max-end-date objects, maybe you should retrieve all of them at the beginning of your BT and then perform your deletes/updates, flushing at the end. If you are in fact performing several UoW consisting of retrieving the top row and processing it, maybe you should manually flush each time a simple UoW is considered finished.

Answer (score 1):

`FlushMode.Never` is a best practice only when you absolutely require fine-grained control. `FlushMode.Auto` will cover 99.99% of the cases without a problem. That said, decorating you CUD operations with a `ISession.FLush()` will not hurt as it only involves a database roundtrip if there are any CUD actions in the internal action queue

Answer (score 0):

Flush mode `Never` means NHibernate will never flush the session, it's up to you to do that. So, `session.Delete()` will not actually delete the record from database, just mark the object for delete in session's cache. You can force a flush by calling `session.Flush()` after calling `session.Delete()`.

I think `Auto` is a better option, with `Auto`, NHibernate will flush the session automatically before querying for data.